# C# MySQL Syntax Error using Update Command

Tags: c#, mysql, syntax

Good day all. I have encountered yet another issue interacting with my database. This time with the *update* command.

**I have a table with the following columns:**

```
Identity Number (int, auto-increment)
Username (varchar)
Password (varchar)
Authority Level (int)
Last Login (timestamp)
```

I'm trying to update the username, password, and authority level using the identity number.

**Here's the code I'm trying to execute:**

```
public static async Task<bool> UpdateAdministrator(
    int identityNumber,
    string username,
    string password,
    int authorityLevel)
{
    try
    {
        await OpenConnection();
        MySqlCommand mySqlCommand = mySqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        mySqlCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Administrators SET Username = @Username, Password = @Password, 'Authority Level' = @Authority_Level WHERE 'Identity Number' = @Identity_Number;";
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Identity_Number", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = identityNumber;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Username", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = password;
        mySqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Authority_Level", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = authorityLevel;
        await mySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        mySqlCommand.Dispose();
        await CloseConnection();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Here's the exception I'm getting:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''Authority Level' = 0 WHERE 'Identity Number' = 1' at line 1

Could someone help me find out what's wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: spaces are not allowed in columns i guess ``Authority Level`` this is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just repalce `'` with `

in mySQL the ` character is used to [identify](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html) table / column names

> The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”):

so your code should look like

```
mySqlCommand.CommandText = "UPDATE Administrators SET Username = @Username, Password = @Password, `Authority Level` = @Authority_Level WHERE `Identity Number` = @Identity_Number;";
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code works now. The single quote and back tick characters look so similar to each other it's easy to make the mistake the first time. I'll keep this in mind and will try not to repeat this mistake again. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

It is all about syntax ' You can use the actual fields of tables like [...]

```
SET [Username] = @Username, [Password] = @Password, [Authority Level] = @Authority_Level WHERE [Identity Number] = @Identity_Number;";
```